# Does Linux keep the kernel stack for zombie processes?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I learned in a textbook that Linux keeps the process descriptors when the process becomes a zombie until future parent verifies the exit status. I understand that process descriptor comes in two structs: `task_struct` in slab, and `thread_info` in kernel stack (forget x86).

I am reading through <kernel/exit.c> `do_exit()` part of the source code, but I don't quite get where kernel stack is deallocated. I can find that `exit_notify()` changes the process' status to zombie. and the rest of the code looks like its about cleaning up  mostly locks and stuff until `schedule()`.

I can't seem to find the part for deallocating kernel stack? or am I not understanding how kernel stacks work?
Or perhaps `thread_info` is not considered to be kept at all and was already discarded along with kernel stack before changing into zombie?

What is exactly going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I think I have finally found it...

```
void free_task(struct task_struct *tsk)
{
    prop_local_destroy_single(&tsk->dirties);
    account_kernel_stack(tsk->stack, -1);
    free_thread_info(tsk->stack);
    rt_mutex_debug_task_free(tsk);
    ftrace_graph_exit_task(tsk);
    free_task_struct(tsk);
}
```

on parent verifying the zombie,

`put_task_struct()->__put_task_struct()->free_task()` does free the kernel stack.

So, the answer is Yes. Zombie processes do keep the kernel stack.

Answer (score 0):

Process kernel stack allocation comes in two flavors:

- With CONFIG_VMAP_STACK, the stack is allocated in VMA
- Without CONFIG_VMAP_STACK, the stack is allocated in kmem

The services to allocate/deallocate the process kernel stack are in kernel/fork.c:

- alloc_thread_stack_node()
- free_thread_stack()

When CONFIG_VMAP_STACK, a stack is actually not deallocated but put into a cache to be reused for a subsequent process (for the sake of efficiency).

The task struct of a process has a reference counter. The task struct along with the kernel stack are deallocated as soon as the reference counter drops to 0. The reference counter is decremented with put_task_struct().

Answer (score 0):

Let's dive into the end of task :

there are two system calls : `exit_group()` and `exit()`, and all of them will go to `do_exit()`, which will do the following things.

- set `PF_EXTING` which means the task is deleting
- remove the task descriptor from timer by `del_timer_sync()`
- call `exit_mm(), exit_sem(), __exit_fs()` and others to release structure of that task
- decrease the ref count
- set `exit_code` to `_exit()/exit_group()` or error
- call `exit_notify()`

  - update relationship with parent and child
  - check `exit_signal`, send `SIGCHLD`
  - if task is not traced or return value is -1, set the exit_state to `EXIT_DEAD`, call `release_task()` to recycle other memory and decrease ref count.
  - if task  is traced, set exit_state to `EXIT_ZOMBIE`
  - set task  flag to `PF_DEAD`
- call `schedule()`

We need zombie state cause the parent may need to use those file descriptors so we can not delete all the things in the first time. The parent task will need to use something like `wait()` to check if child is dead. After `wait()`, it is time for the zombie to release totally by `release_task()`

- decrease the owners' task number
- if the task is traced, delete from the `ptrace_children` list
- call `__exit_signal()` delete all pending signals and release signal_struct descriptor and `exit_itimers()` delete all the timer
- call `__exit_sighand()` delete signal handler
- call `__unhash_process()`

  - `nr_threads`--
  - call `detach_pid()` to delete task descriptor from `PIDTYPE_PID` and `PIDTYPE_TGID`
  - call `REMOVE_LINKS` to delete the task from list
- call `sched_exit()` to schedule parent's time pieces
- call `put_task-struct()` to decrease the counter, and release memory & task descriptor

Then, we release it all.